# How to write an IF statement that is based on an two criterion returning 0 if true and the previous cell's value if false

Tags: excel

I want to check if a time is found in a column, based on the day it is, and if so, return 0, else I return the previous cell's value.

I have tried using `IF(AND)` but it didn't work:

```
IF(AND(Table1[[#All],[DATE]]=$B$1,Table1[[#All],[FINISH TIME]]=A4),0,B3)
```

I currently am trying this as my formula, but it keeps returning '#N/A':

```
=IF(MATCH(1,(Table1[[#All],[DATE]]=$B$1)*(Table1[[#All],[FINISH
(MARKET TIME)]]=A4),0), 0, B3).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to do a match with two criteria where the array equals 1, you have to use an array formula. Click like you are going to type some more in the formula bar at the top and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. It will have brackets around the formula like 
`{=IF(MATCH(1,(Table1[[#All],[DATE]]=$B$1)*(Table1[[#All],[FINISH (MARKET TIME)]]=A4),0), 0, B3)}`
The only thing strange in this formula that I saw was `(Table1[[#All],[FINISH (MARKET TIME)]]=A4)` the second comparison. Is FINISH (MARKET TIME) supposed to be [FINISH TIME]?